# Thymeleaf doesn't see temporals, dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, thymeleaf

> Gradle 2.9
>  Spring boot 1.3.1-RELEASE

```
Getting errors when <br>
th:text="${#temporals.format(obj.time,'dd-MM-yyyy')}" <br>
Attempted to call method “format” on null context object
```

As well as `#dates.format` : Can't find format method

I have `compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:3.0.1.RELEASE'` in gradle configuration.

I want to be able to use temporals.

Comment: Isn't that a Thymeleaf 3 dependencies? Whereas Spring Boot 1.3 uses Thymeleaf 2?

Comment: May be this link will help you:https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time

Comment: I am using Thymeleaf 2.1... switched down to java8time 2.1.0 -RELEASE and #dates instead of #temporals. 
It said: cannot find method format(java.time.DateTime). I put 'new java.util.Date(obj.time)' as argument and now it's OK.